# How to handle multiple radiobuttons in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

I have table like:

```
id value

3 var1
6 var2
81 var3
```

so I need display two radiobutton's for each record like:

```
var1
O Yes
O No

var2
O Yes
O No

var3
O Yes
O No
```

Where "O" is radiobutton.

But I have no idea how I can handle it in controller. There can be more records of course. How I should named them or something else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is stopping you in this? are you confused about how to handle model binding in controller in this case ?

Comment: I don't know how many records I have so I don't know how handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried some approach like this?

//Model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
   public int SomeOtherProperty { get; set; } 

   public IList<MyDetails> RadioButtonList{ get; set; }
}

public class MyDetails
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

// Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MyModel myModel = new MyModel()
  {
   RadioButtonList = getListFromDB();
   SomeProperty  = valuse       
  };

  return View(myModel);
}
```

//View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.RadioButtonList)
{
   <b>@item.Name</b>
   @Html.RadioButton("@item.Id", "0", true); <span> Yes </span><br />
   @Html.RadioButton("@item.Id", "1", false); <span> No </span><br />   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to give each pair of radio button a distinct group name. This ensures, that only yes or no for each combination can be selected.

Comment: Yes, but how can I handle it in controller? I don't know how much records I have.

Comment: Take a look at 'request.Form'! It will hold all the entries. I can't tell you from memory the exact way it will be. So to get more familiar with it, you should just take a look with the debugger.